# How does one reliably check if a nullable property contains no data? DBNull is killing me

Tags: c#, dbnull

I've begun using Massive, by Rob Conery. Awesome little "ORM" and very performant. However, I'm running into issues with System.DBNull comparisons on my nullable fields.

For example, I want to check if a property matches another property (in this example, a long type)

```
if (obj.MemberId == otherObj.MemberId) return true;
```

throws exception: **Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.DBNull' and 'long'**. In this case, obj.MemberId was null (more specifically, DBNull).

Ok, so I check if it's DBNull.Value first right? Like this:

```
if (obj.MemberId != DBNull.Value)
    return obj.MemberId == otherObj.MemberId;
```

Cool, that works, at least while obj.MemberId is DBNull, but when it's not (contains a long), another exception: **Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'long' and 'System.DBNull'**.

DBNull is killing me. How does one reliably check if a nullable property contains no data?

Comment: What about if (obj.MemberId.Equals(otherObj.MemberId)) return true; ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you tried by using `is` operator?

```
if (obj.MemberId is DBNull)
{
    // it is null
    return false;
}
else
{
    // has some value
    return obj.MemberId == otherObj.MemberId;
}
```

Comment: Nope, lemme try it now... brb.

Comment: +1, but I'd suggest taking both objects into account in your `DBNull` test: `if (obj.MemberId is DBNull || otherObj.MemberId is DBNull)`. Unless, of course, you want to consider two `DBNulls` as being equal, in which case it gets more complicated.

Comment: @Chad, (@Frederic Hamidi) is right you also need to consider whether `otherObj is DBNull`, to avoid any exceptions that can occur.

Comment: Thank you Frederic for the heads up, in this case only one side is DBNull'able, but I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @Chad, you're welcome, and be careful to always compare the objects in the right order then ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just using `Convert.IsDBNull` should do.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.isdbnull(v=VS.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!DBNull.Value.Equals(obj.MemberID) && obj.MemberID !=null && obj !=null)
```

or

```
if (!DBNull.Value.Equals(obj) && obj.MemberID !=null && obj !=null)
```

Select whatever applies to your case. This will give you a full proof check.

Answer (score 0):

try this.
this works for me;

`string test = DBNull.Value.Equals(obj.Qty) ? string.Empty : obj.Qty.ToString();`